# Slow Query using MySql, EF and CF

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, amazon-rds

I have a query that takes almost 2 minutes. Can you give me some advise on how to improve it?
The database design as you can see in the Ads class is not great...is it possible to optimize the query without changing column types?

I can change the `AdStatus` column to an integer easily...but to change `OperationType` and `AdType` would require a big migration.
Btw, I tried to do the query just using the latitude and longitude values and it was also really slow.

The `Ads` table has 2.3 million items and the `Pictureads` table has 11 million items

I'm using amazon RDS t2.micro

Also if you see something in the model that needs to be changed, please let me know

```
var queryResults = (from d in ApplicationContext.Ads.AsNoTracking()
    where (d.Latitude >= latitude - radio)
    && (d.AdStatus != "Pending")
    && (d.Latitude <= latitude + radio)
    && (d.Longitude >= longitude - radio)
    && (d.Longitude <= longitude + radio)
    && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(operationType) || d.OperationType == operationType)
    && (!(priceMax > priceMin && (priceMin > 0 || priceMax > 0)) || (d.USDPrice >= priceMin && d.USDPrice <= priceMax))
    && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(adType) || d.AdType == adType)
    orderby d.USDPrice ascending
    select new
    {
        d.AdsID,
        d.Username,
        d.administrative_area_level_1,
        d.administrative_area_level_2,
        d.administrative_area_level_3,
        d.neighborhood,
        d.Address,
        d.PictureUrl,
        d.Latitude,
        d.Longitude,
        d.ExpirationDate,
        d.FeaturedAd,
        d.PremiumAd,
        d.Views,
        d.Code,
        d.OperationType,
        d.Price,
        d.USDPrice,
        d.PriceCurrency,
        d.AdType,
        d.Rooms,
        d.Restrooms,
        d.Description,
        d.AdStatus
    });
```

When calling queryResults.Count() or  queryResults.ToArray() is where it takes almost 2 minutes.

Model:

```
public class Ads
{
    [Key]
    [Index]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AdsID { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_1 { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string neighborhood { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<PictureAds> Pictures { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string UserPicUrl { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n15}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n15}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int MonthsAlive { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceSurfaceRatio { get; set; }
    public bool FeaturedAd { get; set; }
    public bool PremiumAd { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string SunOrientation { get; set; }
    public bool IsFurnished { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int? USDPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public string PriceCurrency { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string AdType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SizeTotal { get; set; }
    public int SizeIndoor { get; set; }
    public int SizeOutdoor { get; set; }
    public int Expenses { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int Restrooms { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public int Garage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string AdStatus { get; set; } //Pending/Approved/Denied/OnHold
}

public class PictureAds
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PictureAdID { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    public int AdsID { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Ads AdsModels { get; set; }
}
```

=============================================================

This is the updated code using Clay Ver Valen suggestion:

```
var queryResults = (from d in ApplicationContext.Ads.AsNoTracking()
                                    where (d.Latitude >= latitude - radio)
                                    && (d.Latitude <= latitude + radio)
                                    && (d.Longitude >= longitude - radio)
                                    && (d.Longitude <= longitude + radio)
                                    && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(operationType) || d.OperationType == operationType)
                                    && (!(priceMax > priceMin && (priceMin > 0 || priceMax > 0)) || (d.USDPrice >= priceMin && d.USDPrice <= priceMax))
                                    && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(adType) || d.AdType == adType)
                                    orderby d.USDPrice ascending
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        d.AdsID,
                                        d.Username,
                                        d.administrative_area_level_1,
                                        d.administrative_area_level_2,
                                        d.administrative_area_level_3,
                                        d.neighborhood,
                                        d.Address,
                                        d.PictureUrl,
                                        d.Latitude,
                                        d.Longitude,
                                        d.ExpirationDate,
                                        d.FeaturedAd,
                                        d.PremiumAd,
                                        d.Views,
                                        d.Code,
                                        d.OperationType,
                                        d.Price,
                                        d.USDPrice,
                                        d.PriceCurrency,
                                        d.AdType,
                                        d.Rooms,
                                        d.Restrooms,
                                        d.Description,
                                        d.AdStatus
                                    });
```

The Multiple-Column index:

```
public class Ads
{
    [Key]
    [Index]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AdsID { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_1 { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string administrative_area_level_3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string neighborhood { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<PictureAds> Pictures { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string UserPicUrl { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_FilterAds", 1)] 
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n15}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_FilterAds", 2)] 
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n15}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int MonthsAlive { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceSurfaceRatio { get; set; }
    public bool FeaturedAd { get; set; }
    public bool PremiumAd { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string SunOrientation { get; set; }
    public bool IsFurnished { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_FilterAds", 3)] 
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [Index("IX_FilterAds", 4)] 
    public int? USDPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public string PriceCurrency { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_FilterAds", 5)] 
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string AdType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SizeTotal { get; set; }
    public int SizeIndoor { get; set; }
    public int SizeOutdoor { get; set; }
    public int Expenses { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public int Restrooms { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public int Garage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string AdStatus { get; set; } //Pending/Approved/Denied/OnHold
}
```

Comment: How many results are coming back. Also, the mysql connection that is used for c# leaves many things to be desired and I would suggest switching to MSSQL to pair with c#.

Comment: A good place to start here would be to use a `take` with perhaps a value of 500 so you limit the amount returned. And then if you need more, you can get the next 500.

Comment: The orderby could also be time consuming to do on the database end. Have you tried ordering in memory instead after the set was pulled back?

Comment: Thanks Travis, I'm getting 3680 results back. I need to use MySQL because of the difference in costs. MSSQL is way more expensive. I tried removing the orderby and it was still slow. I'll try to use the take and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a bunch of single column indexes using the default options and what you need is a covering index that is tuned to your query.

Check out the [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti) section on MSDN for details on creating a multi column index and when you create yours pay particular attention to the column ordering so that it matches your query. You might also consider grouping the latitude portion of your SQL together.

Comment: Sir, you are a God. Thank you so much for your help. A Multiple column index was the solution! now the query takes a couple of seconds!